# Cannot read property name of null reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I get error cannot read property name of null when I try to log the name of target element.

```
 handle_text_input_change = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event);
    this.setState({text_input_value: event.target.value}, () => 
        {this.validate(event)});
 };

 validate = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    console.log("target name", name);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target` identifier is not known in the validate function's scope. Did you mean `name`?

```
let name = event.target.name;
console.log("target name", name);
```

Comment: @gayana Yes, if you pass in the event with parameter name `event`, you can  access the name with `event.target.name`. You did this and saved the name in the local variable `name`, but in your `console.log`statement you don't use the variable `name` or `event.target.name`, you used `target.name` which is not declared in that function.

Comment: hmm true...now within the validate method when i define as below, validate = (event) => {
        let name = event.target.name;
        console.log("target name", name);
            if (event.target.ValidityState.valueMissing) {
                this.setState({is_valid: false});
                this.setState({error: {name} + 'cannot be empty'});
            }};   i get cannot error can't read property valuemissing of null. Can u help me with this. thanks.

Comment: @gayana Thats another question regarding regarding ValidityState in combination with react, ask a new question instead providing code in comments. I can't help you with that one.